# How to open box item animation?

Tags: javascript

I want make 2d open box animation. Like cs-go open keys or other random box.
I need the basics of implementation it and i want get more information about it. Thanks.

Upd:
Steps.
I have array of elements.

I press to button and shuffle array.

I get random element from array by weight.

All elements in array have images.

So , after i press button all images start move with some accelerate to left or right. 6 images move to left. And what is next ? I need get random items images while acceleration is not end ? Or what ? **I need logic example.**

My example realization(I don't know working it or not): I need add to array new items while acceleration is enable or what ?
Or after i get random item by weight, i need sort array and past it item to last position and add other random items to this array. And after all i need loop to this array to last item. And when loop in last position i show it item in screen ?

I really don't understand how it working.. D:

Comment: Presumably you started by searching for "javascript animation tutorial" to get some basic learning materials about how to animate objects in that language? What have you tried so far based on your research?

Comment: @DMGregory What do you mean ? I want to know how to realize it. Any simple example. How it working. I already understand animation and etc. Get me real iformation about it question, But not basic animation tutorials.

Comment: "I already understand animation" great. So based on your understanding, what have you tried? What's different about this specific animation task, compared to the ones you already know how to do? Where are you stuck making it work?

Comment: @DMGregory I updated main question. Please read him , and answer if you know.

Comment: It's unclear to me what you're tying to do. It might help to include in your question an animated gif example showing the kind of animation you want to make, or a storyboard showing each step of the animation diagrammed out. A picture is often worth a thousand words, especially when asking about game features involving space, visuals, and motion.

Comment: @DMGregory What you do mean animated gif ? You can google "csgo open case" or "game open case" and get example video. Or you don't known about it ?

Comment: A StackExchange question should be self-contained, showing everything a user would need to understand your problem and help you. If you require additional steps to understand your problem, like searching out reference materials on another site, then you're narrowing the pool of potential answers you can get to the population of users who will take those extra steps. The easier you make it for a reader to understand what you want, the better the answers you'll tend to get, and you'll tend to get them faster.

Comment: You should not assume we know. Besides, you say "other random box" in the question... Have you seen other loot boxes? Their animation is widly different from one game to another. Given the description after the edit I will assume you want imitate CS:GO specifically.

Comment: @Theraot Yes, he have same logic, where texture rotate around "2D circle", if you  understand.
This is a very popular implementation in different games.

Comment: look for pixijs

Comment: @jon, you posted here engine name, why ? I need source or example code in clear JS. I don't want create big projects. I want only simple example. Why you all don't understand this ?  You're readed my main question ? Example it not full project. Example show how it working.

Comment: you can do in html or css 
https://codepen.io/zbritcher/pen/dGENBd
Nut you need a rendering engine, and just swap textures.
https://pixijs.io/examples/#/sprite/texture-swap.js
You cant do this in vanilla js. or yes but good luck with webgl and shader!